# Website offering simulations of the IELTS test

Tags: resource-request, english, electronic-resources, certifications, test-preparation

I'm looking for some website offering simulation IELTS tests. When I was planning to present the TOEFL I found a website called Scorte Nexus, that offers simulation TOEFL tests, and I found it very useful.

But now that I realized that IELTS is better for me, I've been looking for some web site offering simulation IELTS exams, similar to SCORE NEXUS, but I couldn't find any. I doesn't matter if I have to pay for it, but I'd like to find some place to practice for the test, answering a real simulation of it, and receive professional feedback about my performance.

Could any body help me? Does anybody know about a website offering online IELTS tests?